# wholeTextFile() API Extremely SLOW NOT SCALABLE

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

Issue:  We are using wholeTextFile() API to read files from S3.  But this API is extremely SLOW due to reasons mentioned below.  Question is how to fix this issue?

Here is our analysis so FAR:

Issue is we are using Spark WholeTextFile API to read s3 files. WholeTextFile API works in two step. First step driver/master tries to list all the S3 files second step is driver/master tries to split the list of files and distribute those files to number of worker nodes and executor to process).

STEP 1. List all the s3 files in the given paths (we pass this path when we run the every single gw/device/app step). Issue is every single batch of every single report is first listing number of files. Main problem that we have is we are using S3 where listing files in a bucket is single threaded. This is because the S3 API for listing the keys in a bucket only returns keys by chunks of 1000 per call. Single threaded S3 API just tries to list files 1000 at a time, so for a million files we are looking at 1000 S3 single threaded API call.

STEP 2. Control the number of splits depends on number of input partitions and distribute the load to worker nodes to process.

Answer (score 1):

In hadoop 3.3+  the s3a connector's iterative list calls (`listStatusIterator()`, `listFiles()`) prefetches the next page of results. If you can use them then that page of results is always being fetched while that first batch can be processed.

`listFiles(path, recursive=true)` is best as it eliminates the mock-treewalk, you get all files *irrespective of depth in tree*

key is: start pushing out each file as soon as the iterator.next() returns a path.

Also: call .`toString()` on the `RemoteIterator` in Hadoop.3.3.1+ and you'll get stats on #of calls and latencies.

Reminder: *don't attempt to drop in hadoop-aws-3.1.1.jar into an older spark build*, you need all the hadoop-* JARs in sync just as you do for spark-* JAR, jackson JAR, etc.

Comment: pushing out ... means in practice?

Comment: Thanks so much for your response @stevel So you are suggesting we should use NOT use Spark's wholeText API, but use Java listFiles(path, recursive=true) API to list file... then how to distribute data to executors etc.

Comment: no, I'm saying that the process for scanning files should use the hadoop incremental iterator (FileSystem.listFilesIncremental()) rather than trying to list them all before scheduling work

Comment: > pushing out ... means in practice? 
however the spark driver is scheduling work, it should be queueing tasks to the workers before it's finished listing. Otherwise it's in slow-listing-query-planning hell

Comment: Thanks @Stevel for your response. "process for scanning files should use the hadoop incremental iterator (FileSystem.listFilesIncremental()) rather than trying to list them all before scheduling work" this step is perform by Spark's wholeText API internally.  Sorry I am very confused.  Not sure how should we list and how we let Spark driver to split and schedule task in executor.

Comment: you'll have to look @ edit the spark code there to make sure that rather than listStatus(path) -> FileStatus[]  -a blocking listing of all entries, it uses the incremental listing and starts scheduling work immediately. We are moving to this in our own code & it speeds up s3a and abfs work